# What could cause repeated NULL characters in an .aux file?

Tags: errors, compiling, auxiliary-files, latexmk

I have a LaTeX document that was compiling fine until this evening. I was playing around with `synctex` and `latexmk` when I noticed the error, but I'm not sure what is causing it.

There are over 100 of the following errors when `pdflatex` gives up:

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.18 ...^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@
                                                  ^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^...
```

Wasn't sure what those were. I noticed line 18 was blank in TextMate. But in Editra, [I see](http://cl.ly/50IW) that it is full of NULL characters.

Weirdest thing I've seen. Plus, I can't delete these characters. Anyone know where to start debugging?

Comment: I've suggested closing this question as it seems like a very localised and particular problem that is unlikely to arise for others.

Comment: @Alan: That is fair. Is closing the same as deleting? One thing I did notice is that `^^@` wasn't showing anything useful in my Google searches, so identifying that as the NULL character might be helpful to those who doesn't know.

Comment: Closing keeps the question visible. However just accepting your answer (in a day) should (imo) be good enough.

Comment: No, closed questions don't get deleted unless they are exact duplicates of other questions, which isn't the case here.  So the question will remain if it is in fact closed.  (Also enough people have to vote to close it.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of (or related in some way to) [Compiler gives hundreds of "invalid character" suddenly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84949) Can they be linked somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it was only affecting this file is because I had run `latexmk -pvc` and backgrounded the process. When it hit an error, I wasn't notified, but the shell exited with "a broken pipe", or so Growl told me.

Once I killed the processes that were continuously running in the background, constantly recompiling the document, the null characters disappeared from the aux file and the document compiled correctly.

I feel like such a doofus. I definitely won't be making this mistake again.

Comment: It's great that you posted this answer. Can you please also accept it so that the system knows that the problem is solved?

Comment: @Hendrik I will accept it. SX is telling me I have to wait one more day, first. :)

Comment: Oh my, only now I got it fully: The system won't let you if you don't wait 48 hours first. Thanks for letting me know.