# ! Text line contains an invalid character

Tags: errors, compiling

My Compiler gives hundreds of “invalid character” like this:

```
> !ltext line contains an invalid character pfdlatex
> 1.1
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this matter.

Comment: When I try to comile it gives those errors hundred times

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you entered any accented characters, such as `é`? If so, you need to use the `inputenc` package. Another possible cause can occur if you copy and paste text that includes symbols such as em-dashes `—` or curly quote marks `“ ”`. We can't really help any further without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (as already noted in the previous comment).

Comment: Please paste the code here that is producing the error @Horacio

Comment: If it's the first line, it's likely to be a so-called 'byte order marker', a special character used to show how Unicode files are saved. This is not really needed and is not understood by TeX: which editor are you using?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84949/compiler-gives-hundreds-of-invalid-character-suddenly and [latex-community thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=18299&sid=9f295b16b987bccb0a6be0b5ae640951&start=10#p71856). Note: use [unicode editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) with `utf-8` encoding in editor. May be copy all `.tex` source and paste in newly created `new-file.tex` in editor with `utf-8` encoding, Remove any `.aux` `.log` files and then compile.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the file is in the encoding you are trying to use, and that the right `\usepackage[...]{inputenc}` (or whatever other magic is required) is at hand.

I've had cases where the `.aux` or other LaTeX-written files contained cruft from earlier runs, or just were plain corrupt, and gave symptoms as you describe. Starting with a clean slate might help.